# How to write condition if exist showing alert else add to list

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I need to add data to array list based on product id. if product id exist from array list need to show alert message otherwise  add to list. show please let me know condition regarding this.

```
public stockDataSource: Array<any> = [];

const stockData: StockTrackingItem = {
    StockTrackingItemId: 0,
    StockTrackingId: 0,
    Sno: this.Sno,
    ProductId: stock.productId,
    SKU: stock.sku,
    SKUId: stock.skuId
};

if (this.stockDataSource.length === 0) {
    this.stockDataSource.push(stockData);
} else {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.stockDataSource.length; index++) {
        if (this.stockDataSource[index].ProductId === stockData.ProductId) {
           this.alertService.warnAlert("product alredy exist");
            break;
        }
    }
    this.stockDataSource.push(stockData);
}
```

Comment: I need to add data to array list based on product id. if product id exist from array list need to show alert message..otherwise want add data to array list

Comment: ok so if the product id is already in the product list Array you donot have to push that data else show an alert message ?

Comment: yes bcrystalthinker

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, one such way would be as follows. Though are you sure you want to alert for each item in the array? Perhaps it would be better to push existing id's to an array and at the end display a list of these as a single alert? Anyway that's a design decision just my two cents.

```
this.stockDataSource.forEach(data => {
    if(data.ProductId) {
        alert("This id exists")
    } else {
        this.array.push(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using a filter to get if any existing list of stockDataSource has the productId would be good to check this. Hopping the stockDataSource and stockData will have dynamic values

```
    public stockDataSource: Array<any> = []; // This is dynamic 

    const stockData: StockTrackingItem = {   //This is dynamic
                            StockTrackingItemId: 0,
                            StockTrackingId: 0,
                            Sno: this.Sno,
                            ProductId: stock.productId,
                            SKU: stock.sku,
                            SKUId: stock.skuId
                        };
const ArrayListToBeAdded = [{...stockData},{...stockData}] // a list of stockData of typeStockTrackingItem to be added  // change this to your insertion array
ArrayListToBeAdded.forEach(data=>decidingFn(data));

    //Below code is for filtering and checking the product id matches stockDataSource will have the list at the end


        decidingFn(stockData:StockTrackingItem){
        const productMatchList=stockDataSource.filter(stock=>stock.ProductId==stockData.ProductId);

                    if(productMatchList.length===0){
                    this.stockDataSource.push(stockData);
                    }else{
                    this.alertService.warnAlert("product alredy exist");
                    }
        }
```

Comment: if(productMatchList.length===0)  its for 1st record i have multiple records.

Comment: stockDataSource is your list

Comment: better to make a function and call I think so would help you with the multiple records